# How to define variable which holds $_GET

Tags: php

How do you define a variable which holds the `$_GET['value'];` ?

I get this error **UNDEFINED INDEX: cat IN C... ON LINE 20** while doing this:

```
$cat = $_GET['cat'];
$cat_array = array('users', 'projects', 'roles', 'library', 'bugs');
```

How can I define the `$cat`

Comment: Ok figured it out: Had to do this: `$cat = isset($_GET['cat']) ? $_GET['cat'] : false; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check variable has that index & value first then assign.

```
isset($_GET['cat']){
      $cat = $_GET['cat'];
}
```

Always check array index before use it.

You can read more about isset in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Let me know for more help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you are asking... 
You said how to **define** a variable to hold a value from GET  Array.
Well, there only one way to define a variable,  which is by starting variabke name with $ sign....

Error is Undefined Index:: you might have not written 'cat' named field into the form. Go and check it first.